# Pylint is not working in VSCode but work well as command in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, lint, pylint, vscode-python

When I type "pylint" command in the terminal, it can work normally and show all kinds of errors for me as shown below.
[work_as_command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM91a.png)

But in VSCode, no hint is shown. The editor is as clean as no error existing, although I know there are several errors in my code.

For example, to test if pylint is working I import a function that does not exist. VSCode can not detect this error but pylint command in the terminal gives "classification.py:11:0: E0611: No name 'a_fake_function' in module 'graph_util' (no-name-in-module)".
[not_work_in_vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyAqJ.png)

I installed pylint successfully and enable python linting in the VSCode setting. I also choose to lint python files using pylint in the VSCode setting. I don't know what else can I do to fix this problem. (BTW, I'm running code on remote servers.)